# Output task names when deploying with Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

Is there a way to force Capistrano 3 to print the names of the tasks being performed when deploying an app.

E.g. I would like to get something like:

```
deploy:starting
  # some commands
  # some commands
some_custom_task
  # some commands
  # some commands
deploy:started
  # some commands
  # some commands
some_another_custom_task
  # some commands
  # some commands
deploy:updating 
  # some commands
  # some commands
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question, but what you are looking for is `--trace` or `-t`.

From the help doc:

```
-t, --trace=[OUT]                Turn on invoke/execute tracing, enable full backtrace. OUT can be stderr (default) or stdout.
```

It looks something like this (excerpt):

```
* Invoke stage (first_time)
** Execute stage
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke rbenv:validate (first_time)
** Execute rbenv:validate
DEBUG [f8847463] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3 ] as user@example.com
DEBUG [f8847463] Command: [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3 ]
DEBUG [f8847463] Finished in 3.706 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke rbenv:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute rbenv:map_bins
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
```

Hopefully this helps you or someone else.

Comment: Thank you, tracing actually does the trick, since capistrano is just a rake wrapper now.